# Verificar firma eléctrónica

Tags: xml, criptografía, firma-digital

Necesito validar archivos XML que vienen firmados digitalmente; alguien conoce alguna aplicación o página que verifique si la firma es válida ?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar una herramienta que se llama Validador CFDI; liga [aquí](http://www.validaxml.com/) Acá te dejo otra herramienta que hace lo mismo que la anterior (por si falla) liga [aquí](http://www.lacorona.com.mx/fortiz/sat/cfdcvali.php)

Comment: ***Herramientas disponibles relacionadas con firmas digitales:*** Si quieres realizar operaciones relacionadas con firmas electrónicas generada por alguna aplicación puedes hacerlo a través de la Administración del Gobierno de España.
[Operaciones disponibles desde la Administración del Gobierno de España](https://valide.redsara.es/valide/?) > Desde el enlace anterior puedes hacer varias operaciones, pero si solo
> quieres validar las firmas accede al siguiente enlace:[Validación de
> firma digital (XML)](https://valide.redsara.es/valide/validarFirma/ejecutar.html;jsessionid=598992D5A01D357D46

Answer (score 3):

Aqui te dejo un ejmplo en .net

```
    private bool verifica(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        // *** Load the doc this time
        SignedXml sdoc = new SignedXml(doc);

        // *** Find the signature and load it into SignedXml
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        sdoc.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        // *** Now read the actual signature and validate
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        bool result = sdoc.CheckSignature(cert, true);

        return result;
    }
```

le pasas como parametro el xml y la instancia del certificado con llave publica con la cual quieres verificar

Comment: Bien, gracias. Voy a probar de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso este codigo para hacer validaciones de XML firmado desde Java:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMValidateContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


try {
    //cargar archivvo xml firmado
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:/archivoFirmado.xml")
    if (input == null) {
        throw new Exception(
                "archivo xml nulo");
    }

XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

//construir documento DOM y recuperar nodo de firma embebida
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS,
        "Signature");
if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element");
}

//cargar certificado para validar
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/myCertificate.cer");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificates(fis).iterator().next();

DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(
        cert.getPublicKey(), nl.item(0));

// setear propiedad para recuperar datos originales firmados
valContext.setProperty("javax.xml.crypto.dsig.cacheReference",
        Boolean.TRUE);
XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

//validar
isValid = signature.validate(valContext);

if (isValid) {
    Iterator i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences()
            .iterator();
    Document xmlOriginal = null;
    for (int j = 0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
        InputStream is = ((Reference) i.next())
                .getDigestInputStream();
        //recuperar xml original
        xmlOriginal = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);

    }
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Para más información visiten la [documentación del API de firma de Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).